# Are trivial edits okay if I have full editing privileges?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just notice a [minor edit on another site](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/revisions/10334/2). If it would have been up for review, it certainly would have been rejected.

After checking against other sites where I don't have the edit anywhere privilege, I noticed that when I'm editing on SO I don't get the limitations displayed any more that my edit should be substantial.

I am confused because I am allowed to edit even for a single typo. But am I supposed to be able to? I know that trivial edits are not appreciated.

So which is it?  Are minor edits acceptable for users that have full editing privileges?

Comment: ...I really want to fix ur post to say 'noticed' instead of 'notice' now...... :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Sure, they are acceptable; otherwise it would be completely impossible for *anyone* to fix a typo in a post without making otherwise unnecessary substantial changes to the text.

Editing restrictions are relaxed with full editing privileges because we generally trust that you know what you're doing. Of course, there are exceptions: making lots of minor edits in a short period of time is still frowned upon because it can be seen as annoying (as it clutters the "active" tab in the questions list) or low-effort, and repeatedly making minor edits to bump a post over a period of time is seen as abusive because you're not actually trying to improve your post with those bump edits.

Comment: *making lots of minor edits in a short period of time is still frowned upon* i.e. Don't go looking for minor edits, but feel free to occasionally fix them when you run across them.

Comment: @pnuts: Some people go actively searching for common typos, this clogs the updated posts stream (and taking them out is no good either as the peer review is extremely valuable, yet lots of small fixes devalue this greatly).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98287/discussion-between-david-mulder-and-pnuts).

Comment: @pnuts: It's called being considerate. Some people may not mind, but I guarantee you a lot of people do regardless of how useful those edits actually are.

Comment: Maybe we should smartly detect typo/trivial/minor edits and in these cases not flagging the question as active.

Comment: @BoltClock well, I would hope that they would be more considerate and accept my answers, don't downvote my posts, and not filling my inbox of "thanks", and I want a pony too. ;) But more seriously, how many edits are done on SO in a second, yet I don't see anything screaming?

Comment: @Braiam: "how many edits are done on SO in a second" Clearly, not nearly enough for the front page to constantly be full of new posts on every refresh, and that when someone edits dozens of post in a matter of minutes, their name gets plastered all over the front page.

Comment: @BoltClock as far I know, the homepage isn't even an "active" tab, but something that mix several criteria. Even if I edited a hundred of questions in a single tag, your homepage may not even have 3 posts of mine.

Comment: @BoltClock I regularly see the same couple editors crapping up my active page with worthless trivial edits (like removing a single tag from a **blatantly** off-topic question without VTC). It happens.