# Do the instructions for the edit review queue need to be improved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I received a four-day suspension for accepting a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27386987) that capitalized all instances of the pronoun "I", which were previously lowercase.

The suspension notice reads:

> You approved poor edits to this post suggested-edits/27386987, which should have been rejected. Please pay more attention to each review in future. Being suspended can be a frustrating experience, but your help in moderation is still important. In the meantime, you can refer to What are the review queues, and how do they work? for more information, and revisit your recent reviews to see if you could have taken a different action instead.

The edit was accepted as approved the same day I reviewed it, but then I received a suspension the following day for suggesting the edit be accepted.

This is my first suspension that I'm aware of. Is there something about this I'm not understanding? It seems like this is in error and I shouldn't have been suspended.

---

**Edit:** The answers and comments so far have provided good feedback about why approving this particular edit may have been seen as punishable behavior by a moderator.

However, the instructions given to reviewers are as follows:

> - Approve edits that clearly improve the post
> - Improve Edit when you can make additional improvements to the post
> - Reject and Edit to replace an ineffective edit with your own substantive changes
> - Reject edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

Editing a post to correct repetitively bad grammar is a clear and substantive improvement to a post.

Nowhere in the in-queue instructions does it state that—as a rule—an edit should "fix everything in the post" as [@bad_coder interprets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402263/5351721) the help docs as suggesting. Nor do the instructions state that edits to closed questions must improve the question enough to make it re-openable, as [Alexei details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402264/5351721) in their own personal guidelines for edits (although it's a reasonable requirement and I can understand moderators sharing this view).

I've encountered several unwritten rules like this over my years of contributions to SO. Each time it's frustrating as a user. I think either more work needs to go into making the instructions and guidance for users reflect the accepted norms moderators are enforcing, or more oversight or reminders need to be in place so that moderators consistently enforce the guidelines provided to users. As someone who reads instructions, I shouldn't have to be given a suspension and then ask a post on Meta to learn the secret proper way to fulfill my role as a contributor.

Should the instructions for the edit review queue be revised to provide more guidance?

---

**A note** for future contributors: Answers should primarily address the question "should the instructions be improved". The question is *not* "should this edit have been accepted".

Comment: The question was closed, and the suggested edit did not make the question re-openable, so approving such an edit (which is also trivial) bumps it into the reopen queue, resulting in more pain for reviewers who have to keep the question closed. But the site UI doesn't make this recommended course of action clear. Doubtful that suspension is warranted, though.

Comment: On top of what @CertainPerformance said, that particular question (which asks, with no detail, how to build a web app using JavaScript) is also completely unsalvageable. No amount of editing can fix it, and that edit doesn't even attempt to fix anything meaningful, just capitalizes some "i"s and fixes a mistake in the Markdown usage. A script could have made a more useful edit, because it doesn't even fix all the capitalization issues: JavaScript is still lowercase. All of that said: the guidance on approving trivial improvements is unclear, and edits sending posts to reopen review is bad.

Comment: That suggested edit might be considered as [turd-polishing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260302/requesting-a-stop-polishing-turds-edit-suggestion-reject-reason)...

Comment: "The edit was accepted as approved the same day I reviewed it, but then I received a suspension the following day for suggesting the edit be accepted." - Just because the edit was approved does not mean it should have been approved or you were the only user to be suspended for approving the edit.  What actually happened is somebody decided to improve the edit, this person had enough reputation to propose edits without a review process, and thus the edit was approved.  The changes to that particular question did not improve it to a point so it could be answered.

Comment: I would like to add the fact, review suspensions, are rarely over the first mistake.

Comment: When a user with edit privileges that don't require going through the approval process "improves" an existing edit, as has happened with this question, the original edit is automatically approved. That's why it was ultimately approved.

Comment: Maybe edits that are not by original author should not bump closed questions?  IIUC editors should not change questions and answers _meaning_ anyway, only clarify their presentation, so how would it affect decision to reopen?

Comment: Also note that only the first edit of a closed post sends it to the reopen review queue (that includes edits that are made before the post is closed but approved after it's closed). So if you make or approve such an edit you are robbing the OP of their chance to fix it before it gets reviewed. Of course, in this particular case the OP is highly unlikely to edit the post into an acceptable state, and performing cosmetic edits on it is just wasting the time & energy of the editor, the people in the edit approval queue, and the people in the reopen review queue.

Comment: What about the [help entry for edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), where it says _"Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."_? Someone who review suggested edits is supposedly familiarized with what a good edit is, right?

Comment: Your edit to the question invalidated the existing answers. That's not polite to do. Better post a new question.

Comment: @Sean I revised my answer, I don't think your edit has invalidated any answers. I would, however, ask you to consider that what I have written (in the narrow scope I addressed) was from the start in accordance with the official guidelines as they are given. I have provided a clear source to that end. So please edit your Q considering that I have said nothing erroneous or outside official policy.

Comment: @Sean I also think you do well to press the question and not accept any *"unwritten rules"*. For one thing, to start, the post should be reopened - it's much better and well past the purported duplicate target.

Comment: "*As someone who reads instructions, I shouldn't have to be given a suspension and then ask a post on Meta to learn the secret proper way to fulfill my role as a contributor.*" Whole-heartedly agree. I don't think you did anything overtly wrong here based on the guidance you were given, and in light of the fact that you were careful to follow those directions you read, and were *still* penalized, it sure seems clear that there's some kind of disconnect to address in the system here.

Comment: Without reading anything else I already know the answer to the question in the title is "Yes".  Review queues have huge scope for improvement in so many ways.

Comment: In my opinion, the only reason to reject that edit is because the question is closed. If the question were higher quality, I would definitely have approved that edit. I disagree with the moderator suspending you for that, but given that the edit being approved added the question to the reopen queue, I can understand why they suspended you.

Comment: These unofficial rules are hacks put in by reviewers to make up for a very flawed system. In theory the official rules are fine, something else (e.g,. the whole suggested edit system) needs fixing. Contributors that want to help should be able to suggest *any useful edit* (no matter how minor or major) as they want, regardless of rep, considering how much stuff needs fixing on this site that *nobody's ever coming back to*. I'm not saying that's the system we have right now, but it's the system we should have. Frankly I personally am not interested in playing games with robo-reviewers anymore.

Comment: Generally the opinions on this are more or less "the review system gives me questions I am not an expert in so contributors shouldn't change things that sound scary" and "the review system requires my attention as an expert so make it worth my time", and those two things are contradictory most of the time. The answer isn't to forget these concerns and let everything past the review system, it's to take something that used to be OK with a few users (i.e., case by case review by experts) and scale it to a site this size. I'm not saying it's easy, I'm not a CM or web designer.

Comment: There's a danger that the enforcement is fixing the wrong problem. An edit made in good faith seems to have caused difficulties because the question was closed. Was the person who suggested the edit penalized? If not, why not? If different rules apply to questions that are closed, can we ensure that editors and reviewers are clearly instructed to follow those rules?

Comment: You can refer to [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/395911/5211833) on how and which edits push a question into the reopen queue automatically. The problem here was, at least if I were a reviewer, that accepting this edit would rob the OP of the chance to edit their post to be on-topic and get it into the reopen queue. This is not only a point of failure of the guidance in the edit review queue, but also in how posts get into the reopen queue.

Comment: A lot of responses here fall back on, "Well, editing a closed question puts it on the reopen queue, so approving the edit triggered headaches for other reviewers."  But... _why_? Why does **any** edit send a post to the reopen queue? Because it's _assumed_ any edit will make the post reopenable. Why is an edit **assumed** to make the post reopenable? Well, because _any_ edit sends the post to the reopen queue. That feels like awfully circular logic, though I can't be 100% sure because I'm pretty dizzy from all the circular logic.

Comment: And without a big, flashing _warning_ to that effect next to the "approve" button for edits on closed posts, the explanation for this feels a little like, "Your approval triggered a trap built into the review system, so now we have to give you a time out so you'll learn not to set off traps in the future, because setting off traps is bad and we want to be sure everyone knows where these hidden traps are and how to avoid them." I mean... I guess it's _a_ system.

Comment: @SecurityHound It was in my case.  Or, I had been suspended before and not known it.

Comment: @WayneConrad - You were likely suspended before

Comment: @SecurityHound Should we be relying on past review suspensions to inform new ones if the review suspension process is as flawed as it is? Seems like that is compounding an issue rather than mitigating it.

Comment: @Sean - The only part of the suspension process that is flawed is that you are not notified of a review suspension in more obvious ways than attempting to perform a review.  Yes;  Previous review suspension should be used, to determine the length of another review suspension.

Comment: @SecurityHound There's a lot of other commenters and answerers on this post that would strongly disagree with the assessment that there isn't anything wrong with the review suspension process.

Comment: Making it clear your suspended is the biggest problem, increasing the length of a suspension based on previous suspensions, isn’t one of those faults.

Comment: @SecurityHound That's not relevant to this question, though. I shouldn't have been suspended in the first place, but now this suspension will make it more likely for me to receive future suspensions, which may also be unwarranted.

Comment: @SecurityHound Thjat's my guess.  But that the system let it come to a suspension without me every being aware I had done anything wrong, that's unforgivable to me.  I'll never review anything here again.

Answer (score 11):

I would have rejected it for the reason indicated in @CertainPerformance's excellent comment (quoted in full below, since comments are transient):

> The question was closed, and the suggested edit did not make the question re-openable, so approving such an edit (which is also trivial) bumps it into the reopen queue, resulting in more pain for reviewers who have to keep the question closed. But the site UI doesn't make this recommended course of action clear. Doubtful that suspension is warranted, though.

I would add, though, that I really don't see how this particular question could possibly be salvaged through *any* edit without completely changing the question (which isn't permitted in this case because that would invalidate the answer). That being said, editing questions like that at all is a waste of time - they should be closed and deleted (or allowed to Roomba). Approving edits on them would just send them to the reopen queue, which would waste even more time on a question that simply can't be salvaged.

That being said, I agree that the UI is poor in this case. It isn't at all clear when you should (and shouldn't) approve reviews, and that information isn't really all *that* clear from the Help Center. You almost have to dig through Meta for that.

I'd definitely suggest improving the UI, as well as adding information to the help center and/or adding this to the FAQ so that there's clearer guidance for reviewers on this point.

Comment: The UI should also inform editors that the question is closed and unless they make the question reopenable, they shouldn't edit at all.

Comment: *The question was closed, and the suggested edit did not make the question re-openable* - how was the reviewer suuposed to know that? Please see the bug post I opened [“closed” does not show up in the review if the title of the closed question was edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402285/closed-does-not-show-up-in-the-review-if-the-title-of-the-closed-question-was)

Answer (score 7):

The editing spirit roughly is: "make content that should stay on the site better".

My rules for edits:

- Open, good question -> any edits that make question a bit better
- Open, low quality question -> edits that make question at least readable (i.e. fixing totally bogus code formatting) are ok, ideally should be done by someone with more than 2,000 reputation, [as their edits do not have to be reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), or edits that make question a good question (also such edits would be generally too drastic and should not be approved, OP can still approve).
- Closed questions -> edit must make question re-openable.

The edit in question is definitely not making that low quality post *significantly* more readable (I have yet to see a person who can't read text with lowercase "i"), does not fix all problems with the post (pretty much everything in the post is fluff and should be removed - "I have tried searching on the web" is never useful without details, bold probably should go and some empty lines could help) and finally the edit did not make the closed question re-openable. Approving such edits sends a wrong signal to the editor: that such partial edits are welcome on the site.

I believe that the short suspension did exactly what it is designed for; it made you reflect on the decision and ask for clarifications on meta.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've modified the question and I'm curious to get your thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

It's fact the post was unsalvageable and should have been closed.

If a single orthographic error is systematically repeated—not capitalizing the first person personal pronoun **"i"** several times—[that is enough reason to edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312722).

However the above is still subject to the **stronger rule** for making or approving an edit: **That the edit fixes everything in the post.**

Besides that, the edit did not consistently stylize the word *"JavaScript"* you can see it written with different capitalization and [wrong stylizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) in the post. The two paragraphs should also have a blank line between them (the prevalent formatting choice.)

In this scenario you aren't doing the editor any favors by approving their suggestion. Their work wasn't substantial, approving the edit will encourage continued poor practices, and they will lose the +2 rep when the post eventually gets deleted...

**EDIT:**

The original post has been elaborated on, so I'll extend my answer by pointing out the official guidelines given from https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

> #### When should I edit posts?
>
> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, **correcting all problems that you observe**.

Comment: I'm sure this answer simply tries to shed light on the rules/operation of the site, but rejecting someone's work - where there is no issue with said work - because the *volunteer contributor* could have *worked more* is a great way to lose contributors once they understand how the site treats them.

Comment: @D.SM I did not say that, if I see a suggested edit that needs improvement I will improve it. That way if the user who suggested the edit cares to notice he'll be shown what should have been done. I'll reject a suggestion that I improve only if it introduces serious mistakes or is extreme low effort (eg under 1 minute) compared to what was actually needed to overhaul the post.

Comment: I understand, my comment was aimed at the way the site operates (or is managed by the people in charge) in general.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've modified the question and I'm curious to get your thoughts.

Comment: @D.SM What about the *volunteer contributors* who review those suggested edits? Is their time not appreciated?

Comment: @HereticMonkey apparently not, since I was suspended for following instructions by accepting an edit that made improvements.

Comment: @bad_coder I appreciate your edit. If the review queue instructions linked to that page, that would be a minor improvement. However these guidelines state that editors should *try* to correct all problems—not that they **must**. And this is not included in the instructions at all.

Comment: @Sean you miss quoted me, a guideline is in a way a rule (that much for the semantics). You quoted me as saying *"must"*, I did not use that word! I said there's a stronger rule that holds over the other rules (or guidelines if you prefer) in page I linked. Rest assured I chose my words carefully, because otherwise people would be giving me a hard time. That being said, I really would appreciate you edit out the miss quote that's attributed to me.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I interpret a "rule" as something you "must" do, which is where that came from. I'll edit.

Comment: "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe."  Try to observe everything! because otherwise you could get a suspension

Comment: @TimRandall that comment makes me want to stop contributing to review queues altogether.

Comment: @Sean There is no shame in not reviewing. If you feel it's discouraging, then just ask: Does it make me happy?

Comment: @Scratte The point is that SO's quality relies on reviewers. If this is the experience they're met with, others will likely be discouraged too, degrading SO's quality. It's not about me personally.

Comment: @Sean I understand. But if you are not happy with the way things have turned out, will you be happier by continuing? And if you do, will it change anything? If you believe the instructions are misleading, you can surely work with your now revised understanding of the instructions. But there are a lot of reviewers. I'd prefer them to do it because they enjoy it. Not because the feel they have to.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as a general edit, I probably wouldn't accept it as it doesn't make the question significantly better or more readable. The de-capitalized `i`s might seem annoying (or even hurt) some sensitive eyes or some OCD people (like me ;D), but to me this is not a good enough excuse to bump the question up or "waste" reviewers attention. More importantly, **it tells the editor that they did good** (they even gets 2 rep points...) and encourages them to keep posting such edits. The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) **does** give enough pointers not to propose nor accept such edits:

> - Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post **significantly better** when you edit, **correcting all problems** that you
>   observe.
> - Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Please be mindful of this and **make your edits count, so that the new
>   attention is brought to something substantial**.

<sub>* emphasis mine</sub>

---

Second, there is the closed question issue. Here there are two problems:

1. **There is nothing in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)** that states what happens when you edit a closed question or advises against it. There should be at least some mentioning about being thrown to the re-open queue under the ***What happens when I edit a post?*** section. It should also indicate that edits should be proposed and approved on closed questions **only if they make the question re-openable**. I doubt that anyone except the OP can do that, but that's not the issue right now. I (really) hope that you would agree that this suggested edit **does not** make this question re-openable in any way.
2. Even if there was all that guidance, and let's say you now know better not to accept such edits on closed question - you're faced here with a **title-edit**, which reveals the [“***closed” does not show up in the edit review of a closed question if the title itself was edited***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402285/closed-does-not-show-up-in-the-edit-review-of-a-closed-question-if-the-title-i) bug.
   This leads to frustrating situations (like this one...) and I hope will be taken care of by SE. Until then, try to gather some *"clues"*: The question had many down-votes, there was not even a code-block in the question - seems odd. Give a quick-peek inside the question itself, maybe you'll find out that it is already closed - just reject and avoid frustration.

In my opinion, some *acceptable* edits should be rejected if the question is actually closed. This should first be indicated in the relevant help pages, and the bug described above should be fixed for reviewers to actually be aware of the fact that the question is clsoed.

---

In conclusion:

- **There is** enough guidance in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) **not to accept** this specific edit.
- **There is not** enough guidance in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) for how to edit or review **a closed question**.
- Even if there was enough guidance, in case that the title was edited - you wouldn't know that the question at hand is actually closed.

Comment: There is _not_ enough guidance in the Help Center to tell users not to accept this specific edit. And a repository of information in the Help Center shouldn't take the place of adequate UI instructions.

Comment: Aren't the two bullets above enough to ignore such edit (at the very least skip it if you don't want to be the one rejecting)? And also you can't stuff the whole help center inside UI instructions...

Comment: No, those are instructions for editors, not reviewers.

Comment: Those are basically the same... You review according to the guidelines of how posts should be edited

Comment: They're not the same. And correcting all spelling and style errors in a post is a significant improvement and should be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

> Nor do the instructions state that edits to closed questions must improve the question enough to make it re-openable, as Alexei details in their own personal guidelines for edits (although it's a reasonable requirement and I can understand moderators sharing this view).

This isn't a moderator view, it's just common sense. If a question is closed, why would anyone *ever* want to edit it for any other reason than to bring it up to level of quality to justify its reopening?

Now, the edit would definitely have improved that question's quality. The problem is its quality is so intrinsically low that no amount of editing will **ever** make it a candidate for reopening. It is, to be blunt, an utter turd, and the edit in question would have been polishing it.

That in and of itself is not really an issue, the problem is that such turd-polishing pushes the edited question into the edit review queue, where other users have to approve or decline that edit. Everybody who sees that edit *should* immediately decline it as an obvious case of turd-polishing, which means the edit will be rejected.

So not only has this useless edit now been rejected, **other users have had to spend valuable time reviewing it**. Their time has been wasted when they could have been doing other, more useful things. In other words, this "useless" edit is actually not just useless, but harmful.

In summary, your inability to distinguish a question that is beyond redemption, plus being happy to allow an edit that is actively harmful, is why you got a ban.

> Should the instructions for the edit review queue be revised to provide more guidance?

Abso-fricking-lutely.

I've added the [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag to this question to hopefully bring it to the attention of SE Inc. staff. They are intending to roll out an updated review queue experience in December (see [The Loop, Q4 2020](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/10/21/the-loop-our-community-roadmap-for-q4-2020/)) so perhaps they will see this feedback and incorporate it.

But given that getting Stack Exchange Inc. to make any sort of update to even static text, is like squeezing blood from a stone... I wouldn't hold out too much hope. That's the primary reason why much of the knowledge exists on Meta and in the minds of SO's curators - not because we're intentionally hoarding it, but because getting it formally codified simply isn't an option we have.

Comment: On the other hand we often land on useful questions, that are closed because they are duplicates, or for other reasons. Should all the readers have to see a poorly formatted question just because it fits a close reason? If the question doesn't get any views, then yes, leave it alone, but if it is still being used, I would prefer edits to be allowed.

Comment: @user000001 You are talking about the 1% situation. The one that the asker encountered, and I am talking about, is the 99%. Please don't derail the general case with discussion about the special case.

Comment: *"In summary, your inability to distinguish a question that is beyond redemption, plus being happy to allow an edit that is actively harmful, is why you got a ban."* It's not an "inability" to do so, Ian. Reviewers aren't **asked** to make that distinction. I'm perfectly capable of distinguishing which edits make a question re-openable. And I wasn't "happy" to allow a harmful edit. I was unaware that approving it would bump it into another queue. How would I have known that? Moderators shouldn't punish users for following directions because that direction-following makes more work for them.

Comment: How do you know that duplicates only cover 1%? If could be that 75% of closed post that remain on the site are in fact duplicates. I don't have any numbers, but from recollection, I think my close flags for duplicates are about 10%. I agree that editing closed post isn't very productive in general, but have you noticed that Stack Inc put a **huge** edit button on all closed post?

Comment: @Scratte: Not only that, but it doesn't matter if it's 1% of the *questions*, what matters is the percentage of *views* that are affected by this.