# "closed" does not show up in the edit review of a closed question if the title itself was edited

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, closed-questions, title

After recently [complaining that edit reviews of closed question should have an indication that the question is closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402197/suggested-edits-queue-should-indicate-if-the-question-is-closed), I found out that there actually is a small indication that the question is closed - a `[closed]` tag at the end of the title (not enough anyway to my taste...):

[image]

Only to find out later, that **if the title itself was edited - the `[closed]` doesn't appear anymore**. This can be seen in [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27451350) of [this ***closed*** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64486952/how-can-i-turn-a-list-into-an-array-using-javascriptnode-js):

[image]

Whether the way a question is indicated as closed in the review will change or not - I believe ***this should be considered a bug and be fixed*** to align with the no-title-edit-closed-question reviews.

---

As I indicated in my other question in the matter, knowing if a question is closed or not is important as an edit-reviewer, as some *acceptable* edits should be rejected if the question is already closed (probably most of them to be honest...).

Comment: I think the [closed] isn't actually part of the title.

Comment: @Scratte what do you mean? I'm aware the user don't write `[closed]` in his title (it is not possible). My point is that when a question is closed, then the `[closed]` tag (which is **added** to its title) doesn't appear if the title itself was edited (as part of the reviewed edit)

Comment: I see. You mean the title should show [closed]? Note that it's also hidden when a user goes to edit a post, so if it should appear in the suggested edit, if would go away if you chose to "reject and edit" or improve the edit.

Comment: Might be, but if there would be an indication while in the review page, you already know that the question is closed so I don't see it as such a problem as the fact that from the review page you can't tell if the question is closed or not...

Comment: I just ran into this [with this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27438642). Closed question with the indicator missing even though I've been seeing the [closed] indicator as recently as today. I suspect you're right and it's because the editor also edited the title. I opened the post itself in a new tab to cast a close vote only to find it's already been closed.

Comment: @BSMP I liked the comment you wrote on the reject. I might just start using that one until some solution will happen. I actually think that should become one of the standard reject options...

Comment: On a side note: I think the missing [closed]-string is by design. Stack Inc has recently changed the user interface to put a huge edit button on all closed posts. So I assume they actively want users to edit those post, including suggested edits. Having this information in the review queue may be counter to what they want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the latest [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) this bug is basically resolved.

When reviewing a closed question's edit, the title appears both in the diff section and as a title to the whole review. The title to the whole review will have the `[closed]` tag if the question is closed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One consequence of not showing the `[closed]` hint is that it creates worry and surprise in the reviewer. After approving the review you're left thinking you've made a mistake; and wondering how you failed to notice. Then you're left with the concern of a possible review suspension.

It probably also leaves a negative impression on the reviewers in the reopen queue who might think the suggested edit reviewers didn't know what they were doing - when in fact they were given no hints about the post having been closed.

(It can be added that if a post is closed while you are reviewing or improving a suggested edit, you are given no hints the post has been closed since you opened the review. That will, again, lead the reviewers to wonder about the order of events that just took place.)