# How should I handle edits suggested before a question was closed?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, closed-questions

Occasionally, some <2k users may suggest valid edits to questions fixing typos/grammar/formatting *before* they are closed. However, sometimes, a question is closed when the edit is still pending. Is it fair to reject those edits as they would bump the post to reopen queue with no reason (although this wouldn't be the editor's intention)?

Comment: Rejecting is fairly standard at least. Not sure if that's the official stance though

Comment: This is sometimes referred as _polishing turds_, and is rarely seen as a worthwhile occupation.

Comment: I think it should be rejected with a custom message, so the suggesters understand what went wrong, and why they shouldn't edit closable posts in the first place (unless it makes a substantial change that allows for reopening, but that's rare).

Comment: @zoe standard for some, but it doesn't help if one person rejects and two others approve. Seen this often enough, because I also reject edits on closed questions with a custom message and when I check later, I often see the edit approved anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it fair to reject those edits as they would bump the post to reopen
> queue with no reason?

YES. **If they don't actually make the question re-openable.**

I too sometimes encounter edits such as capitalizing `i`s on a closed question. While this edit is questionable in regular circumstances, it surely doesn't make a question re-openable.

The problem with editing closed questions is the following: after editing, the question will enter the reopen queue. [It gets only one chance at that!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239443/571958) So assuming you approve such non-substantial edit, it will probably be voted to be left closed. Then, a substantial edit comes along and it won't push the question to the queue again, giving the question less chances to get reopened...

In most cases, only the OP can salvage a closed question by editing. In any case you have to carefully review edits to a closed question. If you feel bad simply rejecting, you can reject with ***causes harm*** (which is just a confusing way to say custom message) and explain to the editor the reason above.

---

The fact that the edit was proposed ***before*** the question was closed is unfortunate, but ***irrelevant***. The edit should be reviewed according to the current state at the time of the review.

---

<sup>* The review of an edit to a closed question becomes a bit harder when the title was edited as well due to [a bug in the review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402285/closed-does-not-show-up-in-the-edit-review-of-a-closed-question-if-the-title-i).</sup>

Comment: I think it should be rejected with a custom message to the reviewer, explaining why it was rejected. This way they understand next time to not make edits to posts that will likely get closed .

Comment: I really hope that someday only edits by the OP will push a question into the reopen queue, that would take a lot of pressure from the reopen queue and give the OP a real chance to get it reopened.

Comment: @bad_coder I brought the capitalization of `i`s just as an example. Whether it's a good edit or not is not the main point here. The point is that if the question is closed, this kind of edit doesn't advance the question towards reopening in any way, and therefore should be rejected to not "waste" the question's single pass to the reopen queue...

Comment: @bad_coder *thus you propose to block the entire editing process because of a single detail. (Meaning no one can edit, because we're waiting for the OP to make an edit that likely will never happen.)* - if it will never happen and the OP doesn't care for the post, why should we... Also this one single detail you mention is basically the whole point of the edit (to make the question reopenable), so if it doesn't achieve that goal - what's the point?