# Are trivial edits now encouraged?

Tags: discussion, edits, trivial

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697627/why-cannot-i-increment-returned-value) and every answer to it have just been edited with mostly trivial edits.  Is such editing now encouraged, or is this a user just trying to get credit for lots of edits?

I've reverted the change to my answer, but my position is that unless a change is needed for technical correctness then I write exactly what I mean to write and it's inappropriate to change that.

Comment: Generally no, but once a post has already been bumped, there's not much harm in fixing  any and all other issues that may be present on a given post and its answers. Not quite sure what attracted the edits in this case.

Comment: For context Peter is a prolific editor (well over 100,000 edits on [so]) of "correcting" grammar.

Comment: If only he'd put as much effort into writing new answers instead of "correcting" old ones... :(

Comment: *"or is this a user just trying to get credit for lots of edits"* unlikely, as edits after you have 2k reputation don't earn you anything. Trivial edits by users that can do them without review are more acceptable than those that require review (especially if the rest of the problems in a post aren't addressed).

Comment: @ThomA minor correction, suggested edits will always give you the +2 reputation when approved until you hit the suggested edits reputation cap (1k IIRC). It's just that you can no longer suggest edits on posts after you've hit 2k. You can still get reputation from suggested edits that you made _prior_ to hitting 2k, if they're approved after you hit it, or from tag wiki suggested edits.

Comment: Related: ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/8239061)

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the sentiment that "*unless a change is needed for technical correctness then I write exactly what I mean to write and it's inappropriate to change that*"; edits for _clarity_ are really helpful and completely excluded from that stance. That said, in [your answer's specific case (rev. #5)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24697694/revisions), the edit didn't make anything any clearer than it already was, or make it any easier to read... which feels pretty superfluous to me too.

Comment: I think the edit to the question was fair game though; small fixes like making code formatting consistent or correcting highlighting are still an improvement, even if small.

Comment: Also related: [Are trivial edits okay if I have full editing privileges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312722)

Comment: Why are you even bothered by a trivial edit that (only slightly) improved your answer...

Comment: Peter's edit to your answer did nothing to improve it, so I can understand your annoyance.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm annoyed because some grammar pedant decided to change something I wrote 9 years ago that made absolutely *no damned difference* to the readability of the sentence.  If anything it made it worse.

Comment: @Alnitak That is only your personal impression, which will naturally end up being biased. I would say that the original post had quite some sloppy English, and that the edits made this year were generally an improvement. You need to be less emotionally attached to your posts like that. One could also contest the part where you assume that a post from 9 years ago should never be edited.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396620/are-minor-style-edits-ok https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404191/are-my-edits-needless

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike: In his comment, Alnitak was referring to his specific answer. The main change was from `The Integer class is immutable and has no ++ operator of its own` to `The Integer class is immutable and doesn't have any ++ operator of its own`. Personally, I like Anitak's original better but in any event the  change is truly trivial and, were it to one of my answers, I'd react the same way.

Comment: Hmm right, I made a minor confusion. In any case, the key point stands. One may roll it back if they believe that they indeed do not constitute an improvement, but complaining about it is pointless and borderline inappropriate.

Comment: @E_net4isonstrike and where does one draw the boundary between a question on editorial policy and a complaint ;)

Comment: That's easy, @Alnitak. Outright calling something inappropriate without giving the benefit of the doubt is a big giveaway.

Answer (score 7):

There are two issues here.

### Trivial edits vs the edit queue

The reason for opposition to trivial edits **isn't that they're trivial**. Instead, there are two specific problems:

1. Edits made *by users with less than 2000 reputation* have to go through an approval process that involves everything going into a limited-size queue, which is a severe bottleneck. **This doesn't apply to edits made by users with higher reputation**, who can edit unilaterally.

   Such users - including the one who made the edits you're complaining about - are absolutely not trying to "get credit for lots of edits". We know this because *the system will not give them* such credit. Which is sad, because they perform an essential, normally thankless community service. **The site would be vastly worse off without Peter Mortensen's tireless contributions.** So, thank you, Peter. (Although, perhaps you could be convinced to join the strike?)

   As an aside, writing more answers would not necessarily be a good use of Peter's time. Editing for grammar does not require subject matter expertise, after all. But more importantly, we are much more concerned with quality than quantity here. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow (where the scope is computer programming and a few tangentially related things) has about three times as many questions, as Wikipedia (where the scope is *literally anything deemed noteworthy*) has articles. **There is not any real need to produce more content.** The most valuable reference "canonical" questions on the site have *hundreds* of live duplicates from beginners who either didn't search or are too clueless to know what to search for, and often many more that have been deleted.
2. Edits that make a stylistic change that *isn't a clear (even if small) improvement* could be a problem because of the potential to incite rollback wars, or result in people re-editing to switch between multiple equally-good options. Editors' time would be better spent on things that won't be controversial. However, **this shouldn't apply to edits that are objectively fixing something**.

As it happens, I don't think Peter's edit to your answer was perfect, but it was clearly a step in the right direction. If I weren't *trying* to stay on strike myself, I would have edited again, and made many of the same changes.

#### It's not "your" content

**Whenever you post on Stack Overflow, you [license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) the content**. Though the version has changed over the years, this has always been a Creative Commons BY-SA license, which grants everyone the right to "adapt" your content, and thus publish derivative works.

In other words, we are well within our rights to make edits.

The purpose of questions and answers on Stack Overflow is not for the individual authors to flex their writing skills. The purpose is to *contribute to a high-quality Q&A library*. Stack Overflow **is not a discussion** between people asking and answering, so that the people asking can find something out; it is instead a **collaborative effort to produce high-quality information, present it in Q&A format, and share it publicly**.

As such, it is **imperative that we hold ourselves free to improve that content by editing**. We *do not care* that you "write exactly what I mean to write"; we care about clarity, detail, accuracy and tone. (Although we do not fundamentally change the meaning of altogether wrong answers, in theory we fix simple oversights, use votes to identify the best answers, and then polish those.) It **absolutely is appropriate** to "change that", if "that" is

- a grammatical error;
- an awkward turn of phrase that would confuse some readers;
- [conversational language or other noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721);
- [profanity or other unprofessional language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/);
- etc.

(This is not an exhaustive list.)

Finally: keep in mind that this is a community, and we come to these policies (and interpretations of policy) by consensus, through Q&A on Meta. (You may notice that there are [nearly fifty thousand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion) such questions already.) You are only one community member. (So am I; but as I write this I am reflecting what I have seen others propose and agree with here, over a period of many years, as well as what is described in the site's Help section.) But even if that weren't the case, you aren't a moderator or anything. Therefore, respectfully: **you are not in any position to tell us** that "it's inappropriate to change that".

Comment: Gotta disagree, his edits are *not* all good. For example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/425378/revisions is a complete waste of time, bumping a garbage closed question without editing it into reopen-worth shape (because it can’t be fixed). He seems awfully robotic, and should think more before editing.

Comment: "bumping a garbage closed question without editing it into reopen-worth shape (because it can’t be fixed)" - actually, this is arguably a service to the community, because it points out where delete votes can be cast usefully. That said, I did not actually argue that all of Peter's edits are good.

Answer (score -4):

The policy is that even a small change is okay **if that’s all you can improve on the post**. If possible, clean it up fully so it’s only bumped once. But once it's already bumped, no harm in making some more trivial edits within the next few minutes or so. This policy is not new. The policy is to respect the author's intent. However, a non-technical correctness edit might be like fixing spelling (which is obviously good). You can always (as you did) revert the edits though. I do think this edit is an improvement in this case.

Comment: May a time Mortensan's edits do make sense, and when fixing the formatting makes posts clearer, these edits should be welcome by everyone. But where was the improvement in changing "has no ++ operator” to "doesn't have any ++ operator”?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree that particular change isn't a clear improvement, but several other things in the edit were clear improvements. In particular, [fixing whitespace is a clear improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422798); switching code to code fences improves maintainability; and the main thing that seemed to prompt the edit - changing a comma to a semicolon to fix a comma splice - was just objectively correct.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm OK with the semicolon edit - it was the change of wording I objected to (and hence reverted the whole edit).

Comment: Dont do that just change back what you want @Alnitak

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike I have fixed the comma and the extra white space.  I've marked up the code blocks as Java, too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Exactly!*  IMNSHO there's no improvement at all, and if anything it's worse.

Comment: Then that fine...ill agree the rest was bad @Alnitak